# Spring Integration transform Base64 to JsonObject

Tags: spring, base64, spring-integration, mqtt, spring-integration-mqtt

My project consist of three main block: MQTT protocol, RabbitMQ as a broker and Spring Integration.

MQTT protocol send encoded string `eyJrZXkiOiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCJ9` to broker and Spring Integration consume and process data.

How can I decode/encode the data IntegrationFlow from **Base64** `eyJrZXkiOiJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCJ9` to **JsonObject** `{"key":"Hello World"}` ?

What function should i use from *IntegrationFlow*: *convert(), transform()* or *handle()* ? What logical difference between this three?
**Can you please show me the example of code how to encode and decode data.**

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter inboundAdapter){
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(inboundAdapter)
                .transform( ... )  // How to implement decoder
                .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                    System.out.println(payload);
                    return null;
                })
                .get();
    }
```

Comment: Something like `transform(String.class, (in) -> Base64.getDecoder().decode(in))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the EIP are just variations of the Service Activator which is a `handle()` in Java DSL. All those are for specific use-case and convenience for narrowed scope. Therefore you can just implement your own Service Activator to do the job. In your case it is indeed enough to use a `transform()` since this one plays the role to transform a payload of the message.

The convert is not going to help you since you do not do conversion from one type to another. You just have a string as input and probably you want to have a string on the output. Therefore there is no type conversion involved.

As Martin commented you can use that simple transformer:

```
transform(String.class, (in) -> Base64.getDecoder().decode(in))
```

This will give you a `byte[]` as an output. It is up to you to do anything else with that afterwards.

Comment: if i understand you correct i can use chain of transformer to achieve necessary data type ?

   .transform(String.class, (in) -> new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(in)))
   .transform(Transformers.fromJson())
   .handle((payload, headers) -> {
    System.out.println(payload);

    return null;
   })
My frist transform decode Base64 to Json String and in the next .transform(Transformers.fromJson()) in that way i can have a JsonObject ?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Although you don't need to wrap that Base64 decoding result into string. The `JsonToObjectTransformer` can deal with `byte[]`. You might think about using `Transformers.fromJson(JsonObject.class)` instead. If that is exactly the type you expect in your application.

Comment: Artem can you please answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78097626/rabbitmq-how-to-convert-received-base64-string-into-json-object